# $3\times3$ grid filled in randomly; probability of a $2\times2$ grid filled with one element

Tags: probability, independence

I have a $3 \times 3$ grid. For each of the $9$ spaces inside, I randomly populate it with either $A$ or $B$ ($\frac{1}{2}$ chance of either element). Each space is filled independently.

- What's the probability that in a $2\times2$ grid within the $3 \times 3$ grid, it is filled with only $A$?
- I know that there are $4$ possible $2\times2$ grids within the $3 \times 3$ grid. Any pointers on what to do from here?

Comment: You could (a) list the $2^9=512$ equally likely possibilities and count the ones which apply, or (b) attempt a form of inclusion-exclusion calculation.  Both take a little time but not an excessive amount

Comment: It turns out inclusion/exclusion is slightly faster in this case.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Henry would it just be 128? With 4 2x2 squares and 9 - 4 = 5 left, just $4 \cdot 2^5 = 128$?

Comment: Any objection to editing your query to show your work?

Comment: @RandyDennisRetherford No. $2^5$ is the number with $2\times2$ As in the top left corner so $4\times 2^5$ takes account of the fact that there are four corners.  But you have counted many cases multiple times (the case with nine As gets counted four times), so the answer is less than $128$.  Hence the need for inclusion-exclusion

Comment: @Henry i'm now getting $128 - 40 + 8 - 1$ by looking at the four separate cases. My final answer is $95/512$.

Comment: @RandyDennisRetherford I am getting that too.

Comment: $95$ is correct, as I checked by counting, or more precisely $\frac{95}{512}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $95$ you found is correct, by your use of [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) with $128−40+8−1$ and you have to divide this by the $2^9=512$ equally likely possibilities to get the probability

Doing inclusion-exclusion as probabilities ($4$ corners, less $4$ sides and $2$ diagonals, plus $4$ three-corners, less $1$ whole square) would have given $$\frac4{2^4}-\frac4{2^6}-\frac2{2^7}+\frac4{2^8}-\frac1{2^9} = \frac{95}{512}$$

Or counting would have given

- $68=4 \times 17$ with just one $2\times2$ square $A$s
- $20 = 4 \times 5$ with two $2\times2$ squares $A$s adjacent
- $2 = 2 \times 1$ with two $2\times2$ squares $A$s diagonal
- $4 = 4 \times 1$ with three $2\times2$ squares $A$s
- $1 $ with all four $2\times2$ squares $A$s, in fact all $A$

adding up to $95$ again